# Displaying<List> reports in a message box

Tags: c#, winforms

Within my WinForm i have a method that checks the validation of various user controls and adds them to an errorList. When the user clicks the save button I want it to check the validation method and show the errors if any in a message box. The Validate method is in another form and class so i think that might be my problem.

```
 private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var errorList = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Validate.ToArray());
        MessageBox.Show(errorSet);

    }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: 'Form1.Validate(System.Collections.Generic.List<string>)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context, The validate is a public Bool method opposed to a string.

Comment: You probably have to create an object of the class in which Validate() resdes...

Comment: so you want to call that method?

Comment: @user2637869 see my answer below.

Comment: Yes im trying call  Public Bool method Validate but for it to be displayed in the message box its got to be string format.

Comment: why don't you just do var 'errorList = Validate.ToArray();'?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName because he has to show that to messagebox. And it needs a string not an array

Comment: What is `errorSet`? It looks like a global variable, `errorList` is for nothing?

Answer (score 1):

The error `'Form1.Validate(System.Collections.Generic.List<string>)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context` means that you're using the method wrong.

```
var errorList = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Validate.ToArray());
```

makes no sense. You're missing the parentheses:

```
var errorList = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Validate().ToArray());
```

That's only one problem. The method has a parameter of type `List<string>`, but you don't pass an argument to the function.

Also, you said in a comment that the return value is of type `bool`, but it seems you expect it to return a collection of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue because you are calling the validate method that is on another form without mentioning the instance of that form.

Lets say you have another class Class1.

```
 //create instance of your class/form that has this method
 OperationControl oc  = new OperationControl ();

 private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //call the method with form instance created above
        var errorList = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, oc.Validate().ToArray());
        MessageBox.Show(errorSet);

    }
```

Comment: Sorry my bad its not in a another form but another class,  not sure why its not picking it up. public bool Validate(List<string> errorSet)

Comment: then just create instance of that class

Comment: @user2637869 see my edited answer. What is the name of your class?

Comment: my class is called OperationControl

Comment: keeps hitting me with Error  'demo.OperationControl.Validate(System.Collections.Generic.List<string>)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34619/discussion-between-ehsan-ullah-and-user2637869)

Comment: @user2637869 you are missing the brackets on oc.validate()

Comment: they were missing but that didn't fix the problem, the problem is the class is a bool yet im trying to output it in a string. Is there a way to convert?

Comment: @user2637869 you mean validate is returning you bool?

Comment: well the validation returns me error messages in text format if something hasn't been entered selected etc

Comment: @user2637869 then what do you mean that the problem is the class is a bool yet im trying to output it in a string?

Comment: logically i think i have to 1.  create an error set object 2.call Validate on each control in turn, passing in the error set object 3. only if there are errors in the errorset, you need to iterate the collection  of errors in the errorset and display them in a message.

Answer (score 0):

some time this error means you may have the same method with the same name in your program scope. Check if no other function named `MessageBox` exist in your program